# $49,4489,444889,44448889$ is a perfect square.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

> Show that each number in the sequence $49,4489,444889,44448889$ is a perfect square.

My attempt is basically a common one.

$a_4=4444(10^4)+888(10)+9$

$=4(1111)(10^4)+8(111)(10)+9$

$=4(\frac{10^4-1}{9})(10^4)+8(\frac{10^3-1}{9})(10)+9$

$a_n=(\frac{10^n-1}{9})(10^n)+8(\frac{10^{n-1}-1}{9})(10)+9$

After some indices work, I managed to get $a_n=(\frac{2(10^n)+1}{3})^2$, which shows that each number in this sequence is a perfect square.

I'm basically has zero knowledge about number theory. Does any another way to solve this question? Thanks in advance.

Comment: additionally i would prove this formula by induction

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's another approach.

Usually when you see repeated numbers, try multiplying by $9$ to remove the repeats.

Doing this gives
$$441, 40401, 4004001, 400040001,\cdots$$
which is the series 
$$4(10^{2n})+4(10^n)+1=(2(10^n)+1)^2$$

i.e. a perfect square.

Since $9$ is also a perfect square, the original series is also made up of perfect squares.